# ActiveRecord, Nested includes with counter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have 3 tables (a, b, c) and "a" has_many "b" and "b" has_many "c". I have this line c.includes(b: :a), but I need to count how many "a" are for each "c" so the results be like 2 columns. Also there are some data in C that doesn't have b, so when I show them, it throw me an error.

I can do it with a query from pgAdmin and it show me how I need it but I can't make it on ActiveRecords.

The query that works fine is:

```
﻿select count(c.id), a.name from c
left Join b on b.id = c.b_id 
left join a on a.id = b.a_id 
where c.created_at between '2018-11-08 00:00:00' and '2018-11-08 23:59:59' group by a.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A.
joins(:b).
joins(b: :c).
group("a.name").
where("c.created_at between ? and ?", DateTime.new(2018, 
11, 08), DateTime.new(2018, 11, 08).end_of_day).
count
```

returns a hash where the keys are "a.name" and the values are the count of C for each A.

If you only want to count unique C for each A, you can specify  `count("distinct c.id")`.

For more complex queries you can always query with raw SQL:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(<<~SQL).values
  select count(c.id), a.name from c
  left Join b on b.id = c.b_id 
  left join a on a.id = b.a_id 
  where c.created_at between '2018-11-08 00:00:00' and '2018- 
 11-08 23:59:59' group by a.name
SQL
```

returns a jagged array of the results.

As for your orphaned C records, when you query for them you can inner join to B. That will only return C that have B.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm new at this but if I can use SQL why should I use ActiveRecords?

Comment: @HD There are pros and cons with any ORM. Unlike your query here, typically queries are simple selects that pull many fields for a record. With AR those fields are automatically mapped to an object defined by a class, allowing you to stay object-oriented. 

As you can see more complex queries with results that don't map to an object are often just easier to write in raw SQL.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!